# Google Analytics - track which page was the source of a conversion

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to be able to track which one of page A or page B (think: green vs blue background) triggers the most conversions in the end.

Imagine 2 flows like the following (with URLs I guess it's explicit enough):

1. /page-A => /product?id=42 => /checkout => /congrats
2. /page-B => /product?id=42 => /checkout => /congrats

I want to be able to know that, for example, page-A has a conversion rate of 10% vs 20% for page-B. Or put another way, that 78% of conversions come from page-B.

Goals with optional events can help me do that, but (it's tedious and) goals are very limited in quantity.

Any idea appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting up a goal with a funnel?

1) From your GA property go to Admin

2) Under View click on Goals then click new Goal

3) Select an appropriate Revenue Template and click Next Step

4) Enter the name of your Goal and select Destination for you Type and click Next Step

5) Enter Your Destination URL

6) Turn on the Funnel options

7) List the pages for each step (click Add Another step for more)

8) Click Verify your goal to make sure everything is correct.

9) Click Create Goal

You can then view everything you need from Conversions -> Goals

This will work if you have a small number of starting pages. Note that there is a set number of goals you can setup per property. I believe its 20 for a non premium account.